# Dynamics Business Central Azure AD ADAL Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, rest, azure-active-directory, adal, dynamics-365

I developed a bare bones express app to test auth with Dynamics Business Central and ADAL in NodeJS. I'm getting the following 401 error. The authentication works as expected in Postman and I'm able to call the Dynamics REST endpoint in that context. In the JavaScript below I am using the same AAD tenant, client id, and client secret in Postman, but I'm not able to authenticate.

Compared the auth tokens given over Postman and in NodeJs using https://jwt.io/ and the only difference is the header values and the `uti` in the payload.

When I hit me `getcompanies` route I get the following error. I've listed my node package versions at the bottom of the post.

**Error** `{ error: { code: '401', message: 'Unauthorized' } }`

**Source code**

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;
var crypto = require('crypto');
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

require('dotenv').config()
var clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
var clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var azureAdTenant = 'grdegr.onmicrosoft.com';

var dynBusinessCentralCommonEndpoint = 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/' + azureAdTenant + '/api/beta';

var bcRedirectUri = 'http://localhost:1337/getbctoken';

var dynBusinessCentralAuthUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' +
                        azureAdTenant +
                        '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' +
                        clientId +
                        '&redirect_uri=' +
                        bcRedirectUri +
                        '&state=<state>&resource=' +
                        'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com';

var app = express();
var port = 1337;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))

app.get('/bcauth', function(req, res) {
  crypto.randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
    var bcToken = buf.toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
    res.cookie('bcauthstate', bcToken);
    var dynBusinessCentralAuthUrlauthorizationUrl = dynBusinessCentralAuthUrl.replace('<state>', bcToken);

    console.log('redirecting to auth url: ' + dynBusinessCentralAuthUrlauthorizationUrl);
    res.redirect(dynBusinessCentralAuthUrlauthorizationUrl);
  });
});

var bcAccessToken = '';
app.get('/getbctoken', function(req, res) {

  var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + azureAdTenant;
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

  console.log('getting bc auth context');
  authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
    req.query.code,
    bcRedirectUri,
    'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/',
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    function(err, response) {
      var message = '';
      if (err) {
        message = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
        return res.send(message)
      }

      bcAccessToken = response.accessToken;
      console.log('bc token\n' + bcAccessToken);

      res.send('bc access token updated');
    }
  );
});       

app.get('/getcompanies', (req, res) => {

  var body = '';
  var options = {
    url: 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/grdegr.onmicrosoft.com/api/beta/companies',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bcAccessToken
    },
    json: JSON.stringify(body)
  };

  request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    res.send(response || err);

    if (response) {
      console.log(body);
    }
    else {
      console.log('response is null');
    }
  });
});
```

**Node Packages**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "adal-node": "^0.1.28",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some services are *very* strict when checking the `aud` (audience) value of an access token. Dynamics 365 Business Central expects the access token audience to be *exactly* `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com`. In your code, you are asking for, and getting an access token for `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/`. That trailing slash at the end is what is making Dynamics 365 reject your access token invalid.

Change the token request to:

```
authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
  req.query.code,
  bcRedirectUri,
  'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com', // <-- No trailing slash!
  clientId,
  clientSecret,
  // ...
```

...and it should work.

However, there are two important things to note in your sample:

1. The pattern you are following is a bit strange, though it may be because you're in the early stages of development, or because it was just a minimal repro example for this question. You should *not* store an access token that way, because the next person who calls `/getcompanies` will be able to do so calling on behalf of the user who originally signed in, instead of signing in themselves. If you are looking to have users sign in with Azure AD and as part of that, call Dynamics 365 on behalf of the signed-in user, I suggest looking at [`passport-azure-ad`](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad).
2. Especially if you plan to have a system-wide account or access token, be *very* careful returning the original response to the end user. This is true even when developing, since it's very easy to overlook something like that when moving to production, and exposing what could be a very privileged access token to an unauthorized user.

Comment: thanks Philippe, i'm still getting a 401 with trailing slash removed. will try the passport-azure-ad you mentioned.

Comment: 404 or 401? (Your original post says 401.)

Comment: sorry, yes 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Is the user account in question authorized for Dynamics 365 Business Central? (e.g. can you sign in to the portal)

Comment: yes the `grdegr@grdegr.onmicrosoft.com` user, i am using a trail bc instance if that has implications

Comment: What if you remove the tenant identifier from the API endpoint? Per the docs, the endpoint that you should use with Azure AD auth is `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/api/beta` (without the tenant domain name in there). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/endpoints-apis-for-dynamics